# Changing inputs into titles, issue with handling raw spaces

Tags: python

so I'm quite new to programming and I'm trying to learn python as a starter.

I'm trying to make a function that does multiple things (I'm going to use it for limiting inputs on names).

- Rejects purely numerical inputs
- Rejects inputs made purely of spaces
- Rejects null inputs
- Changes the input into a title

  ```
  def debugstr(inputa):
      inputa = inputa.replace(" ", "")
      try:
          int(inputa)
          inputb = debugstr(input("Invalid input, please enter Alphabetic strings only: "))
      except:
          if inputa == "":
              debugstr(input("Invalid input, please enter Alphabetic strings only: "))
          else:
              return inputa.title()
  ```

The issue that I have is that the code will only reject blank inputs on the first try when running the function, if something is rejected once and the user inputs a series of spaces again, then it will just accept it as an input.

Thanks for your time in advance! It's very appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

A more natural way of handling this (without calling the same function from within itself) is:

```
def make_title():

    def get_user_input():
        return input('Enter an alphabetic string: ')

    while True:
        s = get_user_input()
        s = s.strip()
        if not s:
            print('blank input!')
            continue
        if s.isdigit():
            print('contains only digits!')
            continue
        return s.title()

print(make_title())
```

Some notes:

- Try not to repeat yourself (e.g. the duplicated error message in your code)
- Python contains many useful string methods and `s.isdigit()` returns `True` if `s` contains only numbers
- You can strip the whitespace from your input with `s.strip()` and if you're left with the empty string, `''`, `if not s` will be `True` (the empty string is equivalent to `False`.

Answer (score 0):

In python 3, you can use isinstance to check if an object is a string.

```
word = input("Enter string: ")

def checkString(s):
   if isinstance(s, str):
      print('is a string')
   elif not s:
      print('empty')
   else:
      print('not a string')
```